# Nanoscroller does notwork in any of the browsers

Tags: jquery, scroll

Im using the following code for nano scroller.but the nano scroller does not show up.
i have added the the css and js files. wer am i going wrong?

im using the nanoscoller production code from thei oficial website for the .js file.

```
<head>

    <!-- CSS
   ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nano.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="timeline/css/timecube.jquery.css">
       <script src="js/nano.js"></script>


    <style>
             .nano { height: 280px;}
             .nano .content { }
             .nano .pane   { background: none}
             .nano .slider { background: #FED136; }
        </style>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                     $(".nano").nanoScroller();
                });
        </script>

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#nav-wrap">
         <div class="col half nano">
            <h3>Latest Updates</h3>
            <div class="content">
            <div class="badge">4&5<span>APR '14</span></div>
            <span class="client-author">Education Fair - World Trade Center</span><br><br>
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia,
            there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the
            Semantics, a large language ocean. <a href="events.html">Details & Photos</a>
            </p>
            <div class="badge">4&5<span>APR '14</span></div>
            <span class="client-author">Education Fair - World Trade Center</span><br><br>
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia,
            there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the
            Semantics, a large language ocean. <a href="events.html">Details & Photos</a>
            </p>
         </div>
         </div>
</body>
```

Comment: check my posted answer. I checked below jsfiddle in chrome, firefox and. Do upvote and mark answer if you liked it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is your code working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/fcJr3/16/).

Tested in CHROME, FIREFOX

I updated code in jsfiddle and also included your below css:

```
   .nano { height: 280px;}
   .nano .content { }
   .nano .pane   { background: none}
   .nano .slider { background: #FED136; }
```